# Embed image in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to embed image in Plotly graph but somehow the image is not displayed. Does anyone have any idea what am I missing:

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(x=c(1, 2, 3), y=c(1, 2, 3), type='scatter')
p2 <-
p %>%
layout(images = list(
list(source = "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png",
     xref = "paper",
     yref = "paper",
     x= 0,
     y= 1,
     sizex = 0.2,
     sizey = 0.2,
     opacity = 0.8)
)
)
p2
```

Comment: the code works perfectly fine for me with Plotly 4.5.6 and RStudio 1.0.136 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

may be problem in 'source'-

> Specifies the URL of the image to be used. The URL must be accessible
>   from the domain where the plot code is run, and can be either relative
>   or absolute.

And second list you don't need.

```
layout(images =
  list(source = "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png"...
```

Comment: I don't think so, because this is a example from the plotly page: https://plot.ly/r/logos/

Comment: The example given on plotly page also does not work for me: [link] https://plot.ly/r/logos

Comment: It does not work for me either, does anybody found a solution?